# NodeJS (ES-6) - removing duplicates from array of objects using latest one

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const contacts = [
    {contact: "mobileno", value: "123456789", entered: "03-02-2021"},
    {contact: "email", value: "test1@test.com", entered: "03-02-2021"},
    {contact: "mobileno", value: "123456789"entered: "03-03-2021"},
    {contact: "mobileno", value: "558843721"entered: "03-04-2021"},
    {contact: "email", value: "test2@test.com", entered: "03-05-2021"},
    {contact: "email", value: "test2@test.com", entered: "03-06-2021"},
]
```

Assuming an array of objects as above.
I would like to eliminate duplicates and if there are duplicates, delete the one with the  older entered date. The basis for uniqueness should be the contact type and value.

If both the contact type, contact value and entered date is the same, retain the one with the lower index. Correct processing of the one above should be:

```
const contacts = [
    {contact: "email", value: "test1@test.com", entered: "03-02-2021"},
    {contact: "mobileno", value: "123456789"entered: "03-03-2021"},
    {contact: "mobileno", value: "558843721"entered: "03-04-2021"},
    {contact: "email", value: "test2@test.com", entered: "03-05-2021"},
]
```

Ang suggestions to do this in the most efficient way? thanks

Date format used here by the way is: mm/dd/yyyy

I have tried looking at similar questions here but none of them have the condition of using a latest date entered field.

Answer (score 1):

Try [lodash.uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqWith)

```js
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];
 
console.log(_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual));
// => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked except it does not consider the requirement for the latest entered date.

Comment: It seems that lodash will keep the one occurring earlier, which meets your requirement.

Comment: what if the latest occurring one has the latest entered date?

Comment: If you don't want to implement your own uniq function, you can sort the array before calling lodash.uniqWith